# What should I do if my popular question is out of date?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10304863/925719) about a beta product, and it promptly received a good answer, which I marked as such. Both the question and the answer were upvoted quite a bit and are now getting a steady stream of views.

The product has been out of beta for a long time now, and the question and the answer contain code which is no longer valid. It has received an answer that applies to the current version, but that answer doesn't have nearly as many upvotes as the out-of-date answer.

I don't really want to unmark the answer that was correct at the time, because the answerer should get credit for putting in the time to help me out. I just fear that it might be misleading to people that are viewing the question now.

Should I change my question somehow to note that the circumstances have changed since beta and to check out the other answer? *Should* I change the "correct" answer?

Comment: If you don't want to change the accepted answer, maybe a solution would be to edit that answer and add a disclaimer indicating that it is obsolete.

Comment: Or edit your question to indicate the obsoletion of the accepted answer and a fat link to the answer with the currently correct answer.

Answer (score 15):

Post an answer with the correct information and a detailed explanation of the circumstances.

Whether you unmark the other guy's answer or not is up to you.  The impact on the original poster will be minimal.  I'd personally prefer that the *correct* answer be accepted.

Comment: Especially, because that one will be marked and visible. If you just post another answer, people might not even see it.

Comment: Of course, note that an accepted self-answer only floats based on votes; it doesn't automatically float to the top as accepted answers posted by other users do. @GolezTrol

Comment: Really? Cool. :) Well, in this particular case, *someone else* has posted a new correct answer, so I think it's best to accept that one then, and add a comment with explanation (and maybe an apology) to the first accepted answer.

Comment: I would also edit your question adding a line at the bottom then below the line that explain the circumstances including a link to the answer that is NOW the correct answer.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Do you know if that applies for self-answers that are marked community wiki?

Comment: @thegrinner I don't know, but it probably would make a decent question all on its own.