# How to deal with software updates making answers out of date?

Tags: discussion

Several years ago, I ran into a software problem that was not documented on StackOverflow.  I solved it my posted the question and answer to the question so that future people would have access to the answer.  Over time, this answer has accumulated a decent number of upvotes.

Recently, the software framework in question has come out with a new version that providing a better way to solve this problem, and someone has posted a new answer to the question indicating the better solution.  The original accepted answer still works and is necessary for people on older versions of the framework, but a better answer now exists.  What should I do?

- Nothing; let the new answer naturally accumulate upvotes as more people switch to the new version of the framework; this is the fairest solution but doesn't provide the best information to users
- Edit my answer; this would provide the relevant information to users as my answer has many upvotes which are a signal of quality, but doing this take credit away from the poster of the new answer
- Edit my answer including a mention of the poster; this at least gives them credit, albeit no reputation
- Accept the new answer; this is potentially confusing to viewers of the question as there is then an accepted answer with fewer upvotes than another answer (when I view a question that is like this, I assume the accepted answer is bad); additionally, the accepted answer would then not have the information for older versions

This is similar to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263122/2800876), but different in that the accepted answer still works with the new version, it is just no longer the "best" solution.

Comment: You could add a note at the beginning of your answer like "This is for version yyy, If you have version zzz, See *this answer*" where *this answer* is a link to the new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens all the time, for instance when new API versions are released. I myself have updated many of my Java posts with Java 8 versions of the answer.

I think it's best to

- Update the answer
- Add the newer version of the answer

  - If someone else beat you to it, copy it, make your best attempt to improve it, and give credit where it's due. Possibly even with a link to the original answer.
- Put the newer version of the answer at the top

  - Even though the majority of the users might still be on the previous version, your post will age more gracefully with the new version at the top.
- Keep the old version of your answer with a header stating that it's for an older version of the framework / API.

Here are two example where I've done this:

- [Does Java support inner / local / sub methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388584/does-java-support-inner-local-sub-methods)
- [How to replace HashMap Values while iterating over them in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993403/how-to-replace-hashmap-values-while-iterating-over-them-in-java)